# How to open app settings page in react native android?

Tags: react-native

At the end react native bridge is the only way.But is there any npm package which has been worked successfully for anyone?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [@react-native-community/react-native-permissions](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions) library.

Here offical documantation: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions#opensettings

**Example:**

```js
import { openSettings } from 'react-native-permissions';
openSettings();
```

Comment: Can open without using an additional library, see below - `Linking.openSettings()`

Comment: Hey, this works quite well, but i want user to give permissions manually by going into app settings. but when app settings are opened using the method you gave, after giving permissions manually and going back to the application, it does not get rerendered or get updates witht the permission. i need to go to some another screen aand after comming back to this screen will then update the permissions for the app.
please help

Answer (score 49):

You can open your app settings by using Linking library.

```js
import {Linking} from 'react-native';

Linking.openSettings();
```

Offical document: https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#opensettings

Comment: It is not working for me(Property 'openSettings' does not exist on type 'LinkingStatic'.)

Comment: Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: If you're using expo it will not work, for expo: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/

Comment: openSettings() works with react-native 59.0 and above. Maybe your react-native version not enought to use the method. The error comes from TypeScript by the way.

Comment: I am using react native version 0.60.But anyways openSettings() has worked for me fine.

Answer (score 16):

combining the existing answers: this works for me for both iOS and Android (without expo)

```js
import { Linking, Platform } from 'react-native';


const handleOpenSettings = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
    } else {
      Linking.openSettings();
    }
};

// add a button that calls handleOpenSetttings()
```

Comment: Works for me in Expo (v47.0.3)

Answer (score 6):

**Linking API from react-native core provides the function to send custom intent action to Android.**

NOTE - You can send any custom action that is acceptable by android moreover you can also pass data to the intent.

Here is an example to open settings :

```
import {Linking} from 'react-native';

// To open settings
Linking.sendIntent('android.settings.SETTINGS');

// To open GPS Location setting
Linking.sendIntent('android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS');
```

Hope this will help you or somebody else. Thanks!

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: Much thanks was looking for LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS key.

Comment: @FazalKarim Happy to know that it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
IntentLauncher.startActivity({
  action: 'android.settings.SETTINGS',
})
```

instead of

```
IntentLauncher.startActivity({
  action: 'android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS',
  data: 'package:' + pkg
})
```

Like

```
import IntentLauncher, { IntentConstant } from 'react-native-intent-launcher'
const openAppSettings = () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    Linking.openURL('app-settings:')
  } else {
    IntentLauncher.startActivity({
      action: 'android.settings.SETTINGS',
    })
  }
}
```

**ANDROID**

*Wifi*

```
IntentLauncher.startActivity({
 action: 'android.settings.SETTINGS'
})
```

*GPS*

```
IntentLauncher.startActivity({
 action: 'android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS'
})
```

**IOS**

WIFI

```
Linking.openURL("App-Prefs:root=WIFI");
```

GPS

```
Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:Privacy&path=LOCATION')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete answer for both android & iOS.

Without Expo:

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
import IntentLauncher, { IntentConstant } from 'react-native-intent-launcher'
const pkg = DeviceInfo.getBundleId();
const openAppSettings = () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    Linking.openURL('app-settings:')
  } else {
    IntentLauncher.startActivity({
      action: 'android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS',
      data: 'package:' + pkg
    })
  }
}
```

With Expo:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants'
import * as IntentLauncher from 'expo-intent-launcher'
const pkg = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel
? Constants.manifest.android.package 
: 'host.exp.exponent'
const openAppSettings = () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    Linking.openURL('app-settings:')
  } else {
    IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(
      IntentLauncher.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
      { data: 'package:' + pkg },
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { Button, Linking, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

const OpenSettingsButton = ({ children }) => {
  const handlePress = useCallback(async () => {
    // Open the custom settings if the app has one
    await Linking.openSettings();
  }, []);

  return <Button title={children} onPress={handlePress} />;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <OpenSettingsButton>Open Settings</OpenSettingsButton>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import { Linking, Platform } from 'react-native';

   

    const openSettingsAlert = () =>
            Alert.alert('Please provide the require permission from settings', '', [
              {
                text: 'Cancel',
                onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
                style: 'cancel',
              },
              { text: 'Go To Settings', onPress: () => openSettings() },
            ]);



  

    const openSettings = () => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
        } else {
          Linking.openSettings();
        }
      };




    let isStoragePermitted = await requestExternalWritePermission();
            if (isStoragePermitted === true) {
              
            }else{
              console.log('permission not granted');
              openSettingsAlert();
            }







    const requestExternalWritePermission = async () => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          try {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
              PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            );
            // If WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission is granted
            return granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
          } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err);
            alert('Storage Access permission error:', err);
          }
          return false;
        }
      };
```